# Android Toolbar scroll behavior

Tags: java, android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want that the Toolbar will have the behavior of `scroll|enter_always`. However, when I scroll, the bottom of the Toolbar shows under my Transparent status bar, and gets stuck there.

[image]

What do you think the problem is with my layout?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layoutDirection="rtl"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/halachotToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/White"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl" />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/halachotRecyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layoutDirection="rtl"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:clickable="true" />
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: How do you want to achieve ? Remove _app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"_ from _CoordinateLayout_

Comment: Try removing the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` part from your `CoordinatorLayout`. As far as I know this insets its content by the status bar height leading the `Toolbar` to believe it's already totally gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **android:elevation** for the toolbar